# Do all the .ex files have to be in /lib folder when creating a mix project?

Tags: elixir

I generated a new mix project and I can see the .ex file in /lib folder. When trying to run the application from project root path using "mix run " I get an error since the file is in /lib folder.
To overcome that I created a new file in the project root having the start(_type,_args) method and I am trying to set that module as the mod key in my mix.exs but it does not link to the specified module.

Is there any other way to run the application from project root?

```
def application do
  [
    extra_applications: [:logger],
    mod: {Proj,[]}
  ]
end


def Proj do
  use Application

  def start(_type,_args) do
    Proj1.printHello() #calling the method from another module in /lib
  end
end
```

Here is the error log:

```
10:55:24.579 [info]  Application proj1 exited: exited in: Proj.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Proj.start/2 is undefined (module Proj is not available)
            Proj.start(:normal, [])
            (kernel) application_master.erl:277: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

Comment: The `mod: {Proj, []}` line is what tells Elixir which module to use to start your application. Based on that error message, you do not have a module called `Proj` inside the `lib` directory. As for your original question if all code needs to go into `lib`, by default yes. You can [configure](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Compile.Elixir.html#module-configuration) it to use a different or additional directories if you want. However, you generally do not need to do that.

Comment: @JustinWood: I moved it to lib and it does work now when I run `mix run`. However, when I try to run `mix run proj.ex` it prints the output and outputs the error `no such file`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `mix run my_file.ex`?

Comment: I have to run the file by passing 2 command line arguments. Now, when I try to run `mix run my_file.ex arg1 arg2` it does print the output since I have configured the module to be the starting point in the application but it prints this error - `** (Mix) No such file: proj1.ex`. If i just do `mix run arg1 arg2` it takes the arg1 as the filename.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in your `mix.exs` file is to add:

```
defmodule Proj.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      # ...
      elixirc_paths: ["lib"]
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make what @kamil done a bit more descriptive.

```
defmodule Proj.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      # ...
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env())
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```